# JSR 349 validation: ExecutableValidator.validateParameters on static method

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, jsr349

BeanValidation 1.1 spec defines API `ExecutableValidator.validateParameters` to validate all constraints placed on the parameters of the given method.

However the API require it to pass an object instance on which the method to validate is invoked:

```
/**
 * Validates all constraints placed on the parameters of the given method.
 *
 * @param <T> the type hosting the method to validate
 * @param object the object on which the method to validate is invoked
 * @param method the method for which the parameter constraints is validated
 * @param parameterValues the values provided by the caller for the given method's
 *        parameters
 * @param groups the group or list of groups targeted for validation (defaults to
 *        {@link Default})
 * @return a set with the constraint violations caused by this validation;
 *         will be empty if no error occurs, but never {@code null}
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code null} is passed for any of the parameters
 *         or if parameters don't match with each other
 * @throws ValidationException if a non recoverable error happens during the
 *         validation process
 */
<T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validateParameters(T object,
                                                   Method method,
                                                   Object[] parameterValues,
                                                   Class<?>... groups);
```

My question is how can I validate a static method invocation? E.g, the invocation of `Foo.bar` method defined below:

```
public class Foo {
   public static void bar(@NotNull String str) {...}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to validate a static method to begin with? By definition of static, you don't validate the bean anymore.

Comment: I am not validating the bean `Foo`. However I need to validate the parameter `str` in the sample code mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bean Validation 1.1 doesn't support static methods. From [Requirements on classes to be validated](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-requirements):

> Objects hosting constraints and expecting to be validated by Bean Validation providers must fulfill the following requirements:
>
> - [...]
> - Static fields and static methods are excluded from validation.

Some implementors might support it in the future as an enhancement (e.g. [HV-606](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-606) for Hibernate Validator), but the specification itself doesn't. It's still explicitly not supported in the [2.0 draft of the specification](http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/2.0.0.alpha1/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-requirements).